# Clojure.typed basics

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I've started playing with the seemingly quite impressive clojure.typed library, but very shortly after I run into problems, even when trying to apply it to simple functions. Does anyone have experience with the library?

**Problem 1**

```
(typed/ann square [Double -> Double])
(defn square "Square of"
  [num]
  (* num  num))
```

Type Error (clojure_study/ideas/swarm/vector_algebra.clj:15:3) Return type of static method clojure.lang.Numbers/multiply is java.lang.Long, expected java.lang.Double.

**Problem 2**

```
(typed/defalias CartesianVector '{:x Double :y Double})
(typed/ann v+ [CartesianVector * -> CartesianVector])
(defn v+ "Sum vector of vectors"
  [& vectors]
  (apply merge-with + vectors))
```

Type Error (clojure_study/ideas/swarm/vector_algebra.clj:28:3) Bad arguments to polymorphic function in apply
in: (apply merge-with + vectors)

**Problem 3**

```
(typed/ann v- [CartesianVector CartesianVector -> CartesianVector])
(defn v- "Diff vector of vectors"
  [v1 v2]
  (merge-with - v1 v2))
```

Type Error (clojure_study/ideas/swarm/vector_algebra.clj:33:3) Polymorphic function merge-with could not be applied to arguments:
Polymorphic Variables:
    k
    v

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Did you get your answer [from /r/clojure](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2ui551/clojuretyped_problems)? If so, consider adding the answer here for future visitors or close the question.

Comment: For Problem 1 I got the answer: use clojure.core.typed/Num. For Problem 2 and 3, unfortunately not. See [r/clojure](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2ui551/clojuretyped_problems) for details

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is now 3 years old, so this may not be much help, but I was using Typed Clojure in a big production codebase around the same time and have some experience with it. Also, the answers that weavejester provided in your [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/2ui551/clojuretyped_problems/) on the topic are pretty much spot-on, so I'm just going to re-summarize them here to save future visitors the inconvenience of having to click another link.

In general your approach is correct at a high level but you're running into areas in which `core.typed` simply didn't (and maybe still doesn't) know how to behave smartly.

Here's what's going on:

**Problem 1**

This should probably be considered a bug on the behalf of `core.typed`, because there is a function signature supporting `Double` as a return type. You can circumvent this by using `clojure.lang.Number` or `clojure.core.typed/Num` instead, both of which encompass both `Long` and `Double`.

**Problem 2**

This is just a syntax error - that's not how you specify maps to `core.typed`. You should be using an `HMap` instead:

```
(t/defalias CartesianVector
  (t/HMap :mandatory {:x t/Num, :y t/Num} :complete? true))
```

**Problem 3**

Unfortunately `core.typed` cannot successfully infer that `merge-with` (a core function) when applied to two maps of the same type will return a map of the same type. This is a limit of the type-checker. You can get around this by re-writing your function to explicitly merge rather than relying on `merge-with`:

```
(defn v-
  [{x1 :x, y1 :y} {x2 :x, y2 :y}]
  {:x (- x1 x2), :y (- y1 y2)})
```